# Laravel Eloquent where between two column from Table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

What is the Laravel eloquent query for this:

```
select * from `jobs` where 1 between min_experience and max_experience;
```

I tried the below query but this one encapsulates the where 1 with single quotes.

```
Job::whereRaw('? between min_experience and max_experience',1)->get();

select * from `jobs` where '1' between min_experience and max_experience;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably this will work for you:

```
Job::where('min_experience', '<', 1)->where('max_experience', '>', 1)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

operator must like this

```
level_rank::where('min_pv', '>=', $pv)->where('max_pv', '<=', $pv)->first();
```

Answer (score -4):

Laravel have whereBetween query will work

```
Job::whereBetween('max_experience', [1, 1])->get();
```